# Using C# File class to edit file, but throwing exception

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the File class to edit an HTML file. I need to delete a line of code from it. The way I am doing it is:

```
if (selectedFileType.Equals("html"))
{
    string contentsOfHtml = File.ReadAllText(paramExportFilePath);
    //delete part that I don't want
    string deletedElement = "string I need to delete";
    contentsOfHtml.Replace(deletedElement, "");
    File.WriteAllText(paramExportFilePath, contentsOfHtml);
}
```

However it is throwing the exception: `The process cannot access the file 'path\to\file.html' because it is being used by another process.`
I am worried that this is happening because either the `File.ReadAllText` or `File.WriteAllText` methods are running on the file, even though in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) it specifies that they do close the file. So does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: What other program(s) might be touching the file? You're going in the right direction but the problem is going to be specific to you. This is ALWAYS caused by some other application on your system accessing the file.

Comment: "allways" is such a broad term ...

Comment: Note that you have to write `contentsOfHtml = contentsOfHtml.Replace(...)`. Just calling the method doesn't change the string, but rather creates a new string that you have to assign. Also, if you want to delete an entire line, you'll have to get rid of the newline at the end in addition to the literal string.

Comment: I meant to do that in the WriteAllText method, just edited to reflect that

Answer (score 7):

If this is a file on a live site then there's a good chance that the web server has a lock on it.

Assuming your working in Windows, try [**using Process Explorer**](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm) to see what has a lock on the file.

Comment: Does that mean I don't have write access to it?

Comment: Right.  You won't have write access to it while something else has a lock on it.

Comment: Is there a way to get write access?

Comment: You'll have to find out what has the file locked.  See my edit.

Comment: sure ... get exclusive access to the file ... in other words, wait till the other process closes the handle, or terminate the other process ... a friendly solution for direct write access? ... nope ...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are dealing with `Stream` based objects, you are always better off wrapping in `using` statements:

```
String s1;
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(paramExportFilePath, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    s1 = r.ReadToEnd();
}
String s2 = s1.Replace("string to delete", "replacement string");
using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(paramExportFilePath, false, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    w.Write(s2);
}
```

The `using` statements ensure that objects are properly closed and, more importantly, disposed.

Note:  replace Encoding.ASCII with whatever you like (perhaps UTF8 if it's HTML code).

Comment: This is a different solution to the same problem, but doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Steve Yes and no.  It is a different answer, but if the issue is file locking, and that locking is due to improperly released file handles, then this very well may help.